# tesseract.js returns too long string with base64

Tags: javascript, tesseract, tesseract.js

I would like to test the tesseract.js library on the node.js server, but when running the following code:

```
var TESSERACT = require('tesseract.js');
var base64String = 'data:image/png;base64,' + pngInBase64;
var job1 = TESSERACT.recognize(base64String, {
    progress: show_progress,
    lang: 'ang'
});

function show_progress(p) {
    console.log(p);
}
```

It receives an error in the form:

```
Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA ...
```

Is it possible to set (enlarge) the maximum length of the base64 string in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Using `"tesseract.js": "1.0.10"`:

By passing in a string as the parameter to `recognize`, `Tesseract` is trying to open a file named `data:image/png;base64,{bytes...}` and this is throwing the error that you see, namely `ENAMETOOLONG`, the filename is too long.

To `recognize` a base64 string, turn it into a `Buffer` whose contents are base64 decoded:

```
Tesseract.recognize(Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64'));
// have a cup of tea
```

Note: `Tesseract.recognize` doesn't work on a base64 `Buffer` and you will also need to get rid of the metadata: `data:image/png;base64`.

So this won't work:

```
Tesseract.recognize(Buffer.from(base64string));
```

and this won't work either:

```
const base64string = 'data:image/png;base64,{bytes...}'
Tesseract.recognize(Buffer.from(base64string));
```

you need to get the bytes:

```
const base64string = 'data:image/png;base64,{bytes...}'.split(',')[1];
Tesseract.recognize(Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64'));
```